# vertical align all text and put it at center

Tags: html

I want to show the below html content centered on the page:

```
                      Date  :  xxxx/xx/xx

                      Time  :  12:22

                      xx    :  xxxxx

                      xxxxx :  xxxxx

                      x     :  xxxxxxx
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Notification</title></head>
<body style="text-align:center;border:1px solid black">
    <br>
    <p style="text-algin:center">
                Day:Friday
                <br>
                Date:December 5,1997
                <br>
                Time:3.00pm
                <br>
                Speaker:Dr.Nicolas Lam
                <br>
                Venue:WC&nbsp311
    </p>
    <p style="text-align:right">Head of the Department</p>
</body>
```

The result of my code:

```
               Day:Friday
           Date:December 5,1997
              Time:3.00pm
            Lr:Dr.Nicolas Lam
              Venue:WC  311
```

Comment: You have text-align spelled wrong for the center section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a couple of small notes:

1. Don't use inline styling. Put your styles into a `<style>` block or into a separate CSS file loaded with a `<link>` tag.
2. The `<b>` tag is deprecated in HTML 5. You should use another tag, such as `<em>` or `<strong>`. I have used `<strong>` in my example below.

To align things the way you want, you need to use a table. Here is a working example with the above items incorporated, and using a table to format the 3-column block you are trying to achieve.

I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tangledhelix/0e3t3aov/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .table-div {
            display: table;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .left-align {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .right-align {
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>Community College(Autonomous)</strong>
    <br>
    <span>HKUSPACE</span>
    <br>
    <strong>Department of Computer Science</strong>
    <br>
    <strong>Seminar on HTML Programming</strong>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>The Department of Computer Science, in its continuing effort to impart knowledge on the latest topic to students, is arranging the following seminar of HTML programming.</span>
    <br>

    <div class="table-div">
        <table class="left-align">
            <tr>
                <td>Day</td><td>:</td><td>Friday</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td><td>:</td><td>December 5, 1997</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Time</td><td>:</td><td>3.00pm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Speaker</td><td>:</td><td>Dr. Nicolas Lam</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Venue</td><td>:</td><td>WC 311</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p class="right-align">Head of the Department</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

use table tag to do proper alignment
Here's the core for what you want to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Notification</title></head>
<body style="text-align:center;border:1px solid black">
<b>Community College(Autonomous)</b>
<br>
<span>HKUSPACE</span>
<br>
<b>Department of Computer Science</b>
<br>
<b>Seminar on HTML Programming</b>
<br>
<br>
<span>The Department of Computer Science, in its continuing effort to impart knowledge on the latest topic to students, is arranging the following seminar of HTML programming.</span>
<br>
<p style="text-align:center">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>xxxx/xx/xx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Time</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>12:22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>xx</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>xxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>xxxxx</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>xxxxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>x</td>
<td> : </td>
<td>xxxxxxx</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
<p style="text-align:right">Head of the Department</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do this is put the data you want to center in some block element and center that block instead.

I changed from `text-align: center;` to `text-align: left;` and added `margin: auto;` and `display: table;` to `div` element.
(and also moved `text-align` to `div` too)

So you must change from:

```
<p style="text-algin:center">
            Day:Friday
            <br>
            Date:December 5,1997
            <br>
            Time:3.00pm
            <br>
            Speaker:Dr.Nicolas Lam
            <br>
            Venue:WC&nbsp311
</p>
```

to:

```
<div style="margin: auto; display: table; text-align: left;">
    <p>
                Day:Friday
                <br>
                Date:December 5,1997
                <br>
                Time:3.00pm
                <br>
                Speaker:Dr.Nicolas Lam
                <br>
                Venue:WC&nbsp;311
    </p>
</div>
```

and you will get the result as you want :)
Note: you can change the `width` to any value that you want.

[result (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu2tg.png)

edited: some typo and change from setting width to use table instead.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Put all of the text inside a div and center the div</strike>

Put all of the text inside an additional `<p>` and center the new `<p>`

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <p style="text-align:left">
        Day:Friday
        <br>
        Date:December 5,1997
        <br>
        Time:3.00pm
        <br>
        Speaker:Dr.Nicolas Lam
        <br>
        Venue:WC&nbsp;311
    </p>
</p>
```

PS: don't use inline styles

Comment: You have also misspelled "Align".

Comment: `<div>` inside `<p>` is invalid HTML, browsers will undo the nesting.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that.  If that's the case, an additional `<p>` instead of `<div>` will also do the trick.